# Setting OpenGL in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I'm using freeglut and glew32 in Visual Studio 2017, however, I have to include libraries and edit properties every time I open a new project. Is there a way to set it once and forever?

Comment: Did you ever googled for a solution ... there are plenty of YouTube tutorials for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share properties between projects use property sheets (.props files). In those you can set the include directories and library locations (and additional properties if necessary).

If you want to use the libraries in another project you only have to add the property sheet to it.

You can find a detailed guide on project properties (including property sheets) in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/ide/working-with-project-properties?view=vs-2017).

Answer (score 0):

e.g. templates are the best you can do (until otherwise corrected):
https://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-an-OpenGL-FreeGLUT-GLEW-Template-Project-in-Visual-Studio-2017